# Object Oriented Programming Logic

Tags: c++, oop

I am learning basic concepts of OOP in C++ and I came across a logical problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
public:
    void set(int x) {
        i=x;
    }
    int get() {
        return i;
    }
    void cpy(A x) {
        i=x.i; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    A x, y;
    x.set(10);
    y.set(20);

    cout << x.get() << "\t" << y.get() << endl;
    x.cpy(y);
    cout << x.get() << "\t" << y.get() << endl;
    getch();
}
```

I wanted to know in the above code why am I able to access `x.i` [Line 19] ,it being a private member in the different object.Isn't the private scope restricted to the same class even if the object is passed as a parameter?

Comment: Think about how ugly such a common task as your example would be if it wasn't allowed. The point of `private` is not to restrict access from "foreign" _objects_ but to encapsulate _code_. And the code in a class isn't ever really concerned with any one particular object at all, except for the `this` pointer that's implicitly passed to each nonstatic member function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`private` in C++ means *private to the class*, not *private to the object*. Both interpretations are possible, indeed some languages chose the other. But most languages are like C++ in this and allow objects of the same class to acces another instance’s private members.

Answer (score 5):

Variables `x` and `y` are two instances of the same class. They are *different objects* but they do belong to the *same class*. That's why is it possible to access the private member from the member function.

Answer (score 2):

A private property or method of a class means that it is not accessible directly from outside the class scope. For that public methods are defined inside a class through which we can access and manipulate the value of private members.

In the above example you are not directly accessing `'i'` from the object rather you are manipulating it through a public method.

Think it like this:  You have a bank account and your money in the bank is private member.  You cannot just directly go to bank and take your money by yourself.  Cashier in the bank is like a public method that can access the private property i.e. your money, and you can manipulate your money though cashier.

Answer (score 0):

`cpy(A x)` is a member of the class, it can access `private` fields and methods.

The `private` keyword limits intances from other classes (objects) to access the fields. Any code that belongs to a class can access its own private members (fields or methods).

Comment: The question is why can it access the private field on the supplied x object. It's not the same object, even if it's the same class.

Answer (score 0):

A class can access it's own private data members.

This also means if you have any functions that deal with two or more instances (`this` and something passed as a parameter) you can access **both** object's private (and public) variables/methods

Comment: The question is why can it access the private field on the supplied x object. It's not the same object, even if it's the same class.

Comment: @Truth my answer already states that very clearly... In fact it was the first to do so

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the private scope restricted to the same class even if the object is passed as a parameter?

Yes, this is what has happened `x` is accessing the private member `i` in the same class i.e in the class **A**.